# Insertion at end in circular linked list not working in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, insert, circular-list

Please point out the error in the code.

The function `insertatend()` inserts for the first time but not again.

I'm trying to insert a node at the end of a circular linked list, but after inserting an element for the first time, it gets stuck in the while loop if we try to enter data again.

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node node;
node *head = NULL;

node *insertatend(node *head, int value)
{
    node *temp, *p;
    p = head;
    temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = value;
    temp->next = head;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        while (p->next != head)
            p = p->next;
        p->next = temp;
    }
    return head;
}

void display(node *head)
{
    node *p = head;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nlinked list is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    while (p->next != head)
    {
        printf("%d  ", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int ch = 1, value;
    while (ch)
    {
        printf("1.Insert  2.Display");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        switch (ch)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("enter an element:");
                scanf("%d", &value);
                head = insertatend(head, value);
                break;
            case 2:
                display(head);
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The "end" of a *circular* linked list has to be one of the vaguest concepts I've heard of, ever. I say vague and not just plain stupid because you obviously have an idea what you mean -- but whatever it is, this is definitely not the name for it.

Comment: temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node)) ... Are you going to free() tmp ?, and do you realy need to cast malloc() ?

Comment: @Michi certainly not in the `insert` function.

Comment: @WhozCraig From what i see in here, we have a minimal program. So I was just asking.

Comment: if its such a minimal program, please do point out the error for me

Comment: There is no error. Since a circular LL does not have an end, it could take infinite time to find the end. Like a dog chasing its tail.

Comment: For a circular linked list, it's more efficient to use a tail pointer (pointer to the last node), to avoid scanning the list when appending. The head pointer is tail->next or NULL.

Comment: I am now immediately downvoting and closevoting all LL questions that show no attempt at debugging.  I'm no longer going to waste even a second on the code in these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the mistake is here:

```
temp->next=head;
if(head==NULL){
    head=temp;
}
```

When you enter your first element, head is null. So temp->next is set to NULL and head is set to temp. 
When you enter your second element, it does this:

```
else{
while(p->next!=head)
        p=p->next;
p->next=temp;}
```

Where p->next is null, so you will never have the situation that p->next == head and you will always be in the loop!

Edit:
So the solution aproach would be to change it to:

```
if(head==NULL){
    head=temp;
}
temp->next=head;
```

Edit: second mistake in the display function: the loop doesn't print the last element. I just tested it and it is working fine.

So the complete code woud look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node node;
node *head = NULL;

node *insertatend(node *head, int value)
{
    node *temp, *p;
    p = head;
    temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = value;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        while (p->next != head)
            p = p->next;
        p->next = temp;
    }
    temp->next = head;
    return head;
}

void display(node *head)
{
    node *p = head;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nlinked list is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    do
    {
        printf("%d  ", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    } while (p != head);
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int ch = 1, value;
    while (ch)
    {
        printf("1.Insert  2.Display");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        switch (ch)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("enter an element:");
                scanf("%d", &value);
                head = insertatend(head, value);
                break;
            case 2:
                display(head);
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate version, using tail pointer instead of head pointer, for faster appends.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
    struct node *next;
    int data;
};
typedef struct node node;

node *insertatend(node *tail, int value)
{
    node *p;
    p = malloc(sizeof(node));
    p->data = value;
    if(tail == NULL){
        p->next = p;
    } else {
        p->next = tail->next;
        tail->next = p;
    }
    return p;
}    

void display(node *tail)
{
    node *p = tail;
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nlinked list is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    do{
        p = p->next;
        printf("%d  ", p->data);
    }while(p != tail);
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    node *tail = NULL;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        tail = insertatend(tail, i);
    display(tail);
    return 0;
}
```